# Left outer join to two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 1 with a one to many relationship to table 2.
Table 1 also has a one to many relationship with table 3

I want to combine the results of the join but all im getting is repeated values

Here is the structure:

```
table 1
reportnumber
1
2
3

table 2
reportnumber  col1
1              a
1              b
2              c
3              a

table 3
reportnumber  col2
1              x
1              y
1              z
2              w
```

expected result set

```
reportnumber   col1   col2
1                a      x
1                b      y
1                       z
2                c      w
3                a
```

I'm sure this is possible with a left outer join but i just cant get the syntax right

Any clues?

This is what im trying

```
select * from table1 a 
left outer join table2 b on a.reportnumber=b.reportnumber
left outer join table3 on a.reportnumer=c.reportnumber
```

But the results look like this

```
reportnumber   col1   col2
1               a       x
1               a       y
1               a       z
1               b       x
1               b       y
1               b       z
...
```

Comment: you state that you can't get the syntax right, you should really edit your post with the queries that you have tried.

Comment: Also the incorrect result set may help

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy in MySQL, but you can do it with variables.  This has little to do with a `join`.  Or, it has a lot to do with `join`, but you don't have the right `join` keys and you don't have `full outer join`.

The solution is to enumerate the rows from each table with the data columns.  Then aggregate using the enumeration and `reportnumber`:

```
select reportnumber, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2
from ((select t2.reportnumber, col1, null as col2, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 as rn
       from table2 t2 cross join
            (select @rn2 := 0) const
      ) union all
      (select t3.reportnumber, null, t3.col2, @rn3 := @rn3 + 1 as rn
       from table3 t3 cross join
             (select @rn3 := 0) const
      )
     ) t
group by reportnumber, rn;
```

Comment: i don't understand this, but i tried it. it said "every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @case1352 . . . Every derived table does have its own alias in this query.